# How to display pdf file in UWP app?

Tags: uwp-xaml

How do I save pdf file from internet(I have this url: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/example.pdf") to local storage and then convert in image and display in UWP app?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pieter Nijs has a great post about this on his blog at http://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2016/02/06/displaying-pdf-files-in-a-uwp-app/

Comment: #uwp why the webview is not able to render the pdf document